# Why is there space which is neither margin or padding between <img> and <p> elements?

Tags: html, css

Why is there space which is neither margin or padding between `<img>` and `<p>` elements? It seems that such space does not exists between the two `<p>` elements

```css
        *, *:after, *:before {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    html {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 1.8rem;
        color: #333333;
    }
    .summoner-icon {
        max-width: 50px;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .match {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
        <div class='matches'>
            <div>
                <div class='match'>
                    <img class='summoner-icon' src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/433155/pexels-photo-433155.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=150" alt="">
                    <p>Test1</p>
                    <p>Test2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Because they have `line-height` properties. Also, the image in your example is a transparent png and has space in the image.

Comment: I'm not talking about the transparent part. I am inspecting the elements using the inspect tool so I can see their margins and paddings. That space is neither one of those.

Comment: yeah, it's the `line-height`.

Comment: It is both `line-height` _and_ adding `display: block` to the image. Otherwise a few px remain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1)

Your issue is `line-height`. Remove (or reduce) your line height and it works as you wish.

## 2)

Image is default displayed `inline`. Fix this to display the image as a `block` level element.

```css
        *, *:after, *:before {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    html {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        /*line-height: 1.8rem;*/
        color: #333333;
    }
    .summoner-icon {
        max-width: 50px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: block;
    }
    .match {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
        <div class='matches'>
            <div>
                <div class='match'>
                    <img class='summoner-icon' src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/433155/pexels-photo-433155.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=150" alt="">
                    <p>Test1</p>
                    <p>Test2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: There will be still a little space between the image and the paragraph, adding a display:block to the image removes it

Comment: Yes, adding display: block to the image removed the whitespace I was talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Add a display:block to your image